# "Access token has been revoked " on Cognito login intermittently

Tags: authentication, amazon-cognito, access-token, aws-amplify

I am using Amplify to sign in to Cognito from the react app.

```
const user = await Auth.signIn(userName, password);
```

Only sometimes, it will return:

```
 "NotAuthorizedException: Access Token has been revoked
```

I am definitely seeing this error after the password for the user is changed and then the signIn is attempted.

Weird to get it at the time of login itself. How can I try to resolve this?